# Media-queries not working

Tags: html, css

Trying to complete this website

http://www.nsckolkata.com/

The font-face for the header in the menubar (at the top sof style.css) is not working.
The media queries (at the bottom of style.css) are not working.

Tried a lot of solutions from stackoverflow and other discussion forums with no results.

I am putting up the css and the header section of the html. Hope this will help.

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'OldEnglish';
    src: url('../fonts/olde_english_regular/OldeEnglishRegular.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/olde_english_regular/OldeEnglishRegular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/olde_english_regular/OldeEnglishRegular.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/olde_english_regular/OldeEnglishRegular.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/olde_english_regular/OldeEnglishRegular.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/olde_english_regular/OldeEnglishRegular.svg#OldEnglish') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

.navbar-brand{
 font-family: "OldEnglish";
 font-size: 30px;
}

.copyright{
 position:fixed;
 bottom: 10px;
 right: 10px; 
 font-size: 12px;
 background:rgba(255,255,255);
 padding:3px 12px;
 border-radius: 4px; 
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 opacity: 0.8;
 transition: 0.5s;
}
.copyright:hover{
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);;
 color: #fff;
 opacity: 1;
}
.committeedrop{
 padding: 7px 7px;
 min-width: 332px;
}
.contactdrop{
 padding: 7px 0px;
 min-width: 800px; 
 background-color:#fff !important;
}
  
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

.label-as-badge {
    border-radius: 1em;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height:12px;
}

.inlineblock{
 display:inline-block;
}

.navbar-brand img{
 height: 40px;
 width: 40px;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 bottom: 10px;
 position: relative;
 border-radius: 6px;
}

.mb20{
 margin-bottom:20px;
}

.m0{
 margin:0px;
}
.ml3{
 margin-left:3px;
}

.panel300{
 max-height: 300px; 
 overflow: hidden;
 overflow-y: auto;}
}
.panel600{
 max-height: 600px; 
 overflow: hidden;
 overflow-y: auto;}
}

@media all and (max-width:767px) {
 body{background-color: gray;}
    .contactdrop{ min-width:300px !important;}
    .contactdrop iframe{display:none;}
    .panel300,.panel600{min-width:initial;}
}
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="nsc">
 <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <meta name="description" content="Numismatic Society of Calcutta"/>
        <meta name="author" content="Numismatic Society of Calcutta"/>
        <link rel="icon" href="image/Favicon/favicon.ico"/>
    
        <title>Numistmatic Society of Calcutta</title>
    
        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
     <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    
        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
   </head>
```

** Updated Snippet
*** Font face problem resolved. Thanks! Updated snippet. Check the font-face at top for the solution.

Comment: post a jsfiddle or something

Comment: You should add the media query code to your question, when your website is changed/ redesigned this question will become helpful to no-one else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have extra curly braces closed Two times before media css in `.panel300` and `.page1600` style definitions.

```
    .panel300{
      max-height: 300px;    
      overflow: hidden;
      overflow-y: auto;}
    }
    .panel600{
      max-height: 600px;    
      overflow: hidden;
      overflow-y: auto;}
    }
```

Remove the extra curly braces from above to look like below

```
    .panel300{
        max-height: 300px;  
        overflow: hidden;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
    .panel600{
        max-height: 600px;  
        overflow: hidden;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
```

also as I have checked the browser console your font path is wrong.
check the screenshot below
[screenshot](http://prntscr.com/6g5ck8)

also change your doctype to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: I also respectfully suggest using a decent IDE. It will be a lot faster at debugging curly brace issues than SO.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just change the DOCTYPE tag into `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

You don't need to include every font extension. Just use `.ttf` or `.otf`.

Comment: Tried and failed buddy!

Answer (score 0):

Your font is not accessible, that is why its not working. Please have a look. Check it here : http://www.nsckolkata.com/font/olde_english_regular/OldeEnglishRegular.ttf

As you are on Wordpress, you might find this article useful:
https://jeffsebring.com/2012/how-to-use-web-fonts-with-wordpress/

Write your media queries like this :

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
.body{background-color: gray;}
.contactdrop{ min-width:300px !important;}
.contactdrop iframe{display:none;}
.panel300,.panel600{min-width:initial;} }
```

Comment: I still see a 404 error. Are you sure, you have set the right permissions for the file ? Set it either 644 or 755.

Comment: I have corrected the path in... made font fonts http://www.nsckolkata.com/fonts/olde_english_regular/OldeEnglishRegular.ttf. Also updated the snippet in the Question.

Comment: Just add a space in the .navbar-brand { font-family: "Old English";} 
In between Old and English. Thats all.

Comment: Please mark the answer as complete. So others will directly proceed to this answer.

Comment: Media queries are still not working. Just waiting for a little help there.

Comment: At the bottom of the css snippet. The question had 2 sub questions.

Comment: for a thinner view, in the menu dropdown, contact us section, the map should not be visible and it should not have a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: The 2 curly braces are, one for ending .panel1600 and one for ending media query.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a wrong path because of the 404... try the `absolute URL` for the `src` property instead of the `relativ` just to be sure (or give us the absolute path to the font so we can check the access.)